# C# BeforeFieldInit Jon Skeet explanation confusion

Tags: c#, initialization

I read through Jon Skeet's [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx) about `beforefieldinit` and I stumbled upon a question. He mentions that the type initializer can be invoked at any time before the first reference to a static field is called.

This is *my* test code:

```
class Test1
{
    public static string x1 = EchoAndReturn1("Init x1");

    public static string EchoAndReturn1(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        return s;
    }
}

class Programm
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Main");

        Test1.EchoAndReturn1("Echo 1");

        Console.WriteLine("After echo");

        string y = Test1.x1;  //marked line
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Init x1
Starting Main
Echo 1
After echo
```

But without the *marked line*, so without the invocation of the static field `x1`, the output is:

```
Starting Main
Init x1
Echo 1
After echo
```

So the invocation of *objects* that are flagged with `beforefieldinit` affects the invocation of their type initializers? Or does this belong to the strange effect of `beforefieldinit` he mentioned?

> So, beforefieldinit can make the invocation of the type initializer even lazier or more eager.

Comment: Am I the only one that reads this question and thinks "Why would anyone even care about it?"? As long as static members are initialized  *before* they are used, why should we care when it happens?  (Unless, of course, you have a time-consuming initialization process but that's a different story altogether)

Comment: I've read this question several times and I'm not sure what you are asking. The CLI spec says "*the type's initializer method is executed at, or sometime before, first access to any static field defined for that type*"  In both your example programs, the initializer method is executed well before any static field is touched, so the contract is upheld. What's the question?

Comment: @EricLippert Yes i know, i didnt report any issues. I am just wondering why and if the invocation of `x1` affects the point in time when `x1` gets initialized. Why didnt `x1` get initialized like in *result 2*? The code would have still worked fine. This type gets 100% initialized at least (as the latest point in time) when the class is referenced or anything like that. That would be enough because the earlier initialization isnt even required for the code to work.

Comment: @L.Guthardt I didn't say it's wrong, I'm just wondering why bother? Will knowing the answer to this question change the way you use static members or static classes? I can't see how...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Well, it will depend on the answer :)  In some special cases it *might* change my use of it, but will not have a huge affect on it. It's mostly just my interest that i am curious about how it works and what happens on a deeper level.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: It can have a big impact. If you're expecting the type initialization to have a side effect that your program later relies on, you really need to know that's going to happen, and ideally when.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you that at least someone can relate to me and why i wonder about it.

Comment: I think all you're seeing - as described by Eric - is that it *is* pretty flexibly defined; it's all fine by the spec, and it would be fine for "Init x1" never to appear at all.

Comment: Yes ok, thank you. I think i got it now.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok. I'm not sure what impact you are talking about but I'll take your word for it. However, IMHO, if your program relies on something that is, as Eric Lippert wrote in his answer - *"an implementation detail of the runtime subject to change at its whim."* and indeed, as you blogged about, have changed in the past - well, that means your program is written wrong.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Absolutely. That's my point. That's why it's worth knowing about this sort of thing. If you don't know what the rules are, how can you know whether your code is making assumptions that aren't supported by those rules?

Comment: @JonSkeet hence my first comment - "As long as static members are initialized before they are used". IMHO, If you know that, the exact time when they are actually initialized should not matter - all you need to know is that they will be ready for you when you need them...

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Suppose you have a field which is initialized by reading a config file if it exists, or creating it if it doesn't. Separately, you have a static method in the same class that copies the config file. If you're under the impression that whenever a static method runs, the type must have been initialized, that sounds safe (modulo users deleting the file). In reality, it's not - the `CopyConfig` method could be called without the field having been initialized yet, and therefore without the config file being created. That could be a hard problem to diagnose.

Comment: @JonSkeet Perhaps I'm missing something here, but didn't we establish that all static members gets initialized at the same time? As Eric Lippert wrote in his first comment to this question - *The CLI spec says "the type's initializer method is executed at, or sometime before, first access to any static field defined for that type"* Dosen't the type initializer Initializes all static members?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes, it does. But it's not guaranteed to be executed until a static field is accessed (unless there's a static constructor). That's my point. If you only call static methods that don't use the static field, there's no guarantee that the type initializer will be run. I found that mildly surprising when I first learned about it, so I wanted to know more. It seems the OP is in the same state. They've now got a better grasp on what they can rely on. That seems like a thoroughly good thing, and a lot of the point of the site.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think now I finally understand your point. Thanks for your patience :-) !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure what question is being asked here; perhaps if I explain what is going on in the mind of the jitter, that will answer the question.

Static classes with an *explicit* static constructor have "strict" semantics about when the cctor runs: it runs *immediately* before the *first* use of a member of the type.  So if you have

```
if (whatever) x = Foo.Bar;
```

then the cctor for `Foo` is NOT run if `whatever` is false, because we have not yet encountered an actual use of a member.

Think about what this must mean for the jitted code. **How would you write a jitter for a language that has this requirement**?

For *static method calls* you could put a little prequel at every call site that checks if the cctor has been run.  But that makes every call site bigger and slower.

You could put the prequel into the static method itself. That would keep the call sites small, but every call would still get slightly slower.

Or, you could be clever and put the check *in the jitter the first time the static method is jitted*.  That way you only get the cost of the check *once*, and call sites stay small. The jit cost gets larger, but only by a tiny fraction; jitting is already expensive.

Notice however that doing so *precludes any optimization that causes a method to be jitted before its first call*, because such an optimization now introduces a correctness problem. Optimization almost always involves trade-offs!

But for *field accesses*, there's no method to jit. The jitter would have to put a little prequel in front of *every access to the field that could possibly be the first*. So accessing a field not only gets *slow*, but the code also gets *big*.

You might think *why not make the field into a property and put the prequel on the jitting of the getter and setter?*, but that doesn't work because fields are *variables* and properties are not.  We need to be able to pass static fields via `ref` and `out`, for instance, but you can't do that with a property.  The field might be `volatile`, and cannot be a property. And so on.

It would be nice to be able to avoid these costs on field accesses.

Static classes without an explicit cctor but with a compiler-generated implicit cctor to initialize the static fields get "relaxed" semantics where the jitter merely guarantees that the cctor is called at *some point* before a field is accessed. Your program uses these relaxed semantics.

In the first version, with a field access, **the jitter knows from its analysis of the method that a static field might be accessed**.  (Why "might"? As before, the access could be under an `if`.)  The jitter is allowed to run the cctor at *any* time before the first access, so what it does is it makes a note that says **when `Main` is jitted, check to see if the Test1 cctor has been run, and if not, run it**.

If Main is called a second time, hey, it's only jitted once. So again, the cost of the check is only borne on the first call. (Of course Main is only ever called once in most programs, but you can write a recursive Main if you're into that sort of thing.)

In your second program there is no field access. The jitter could also reason that a static *method* is accessed, and that the cctor could be run at jit time for Main. It does not.  Why not?  I don't know; you'd have to ask the jitter team about that. But the point is that the jitter is *entirely within its rights* to use a heuristic to decide whether or not to run the cctor at jit time, *and it does so*.

The jitter is also within its rights to use a heuristic to decide whether or not a call to a static method that touches no field triggers the cctor; in this case apparently it does so, unnecessarily.

Your question seems to be "what are these heuristics?" and the answer is... well, I don't definitively know what the answer is, and it is an implementation detail of the runtime subject to change at its whim. You've seen in this answer what some good guesses are about the nature of those heuristics:

- Check to see if the cctor of T needs running when any static method of T is jitted
- Check to see if the cctor of T needs running when any method that accesses a static field of T is jitted

Those heuristics would fulfill the requirements of the relaxed semantics, and would avoid emitting all checks at call sites, and would still ensure reasonable behaviour.

But you can't rely on those guesses. All you can rely on is that the cctor will get run at *some* point before the first field access, and that's what you're getting. Whether or not there is a field access in a particular method is plainly a part of that heuristic, but those heuristics could change.

Comment: "but those heuristics could change" - and indeed did: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/

Comment: @wardies: That documentation is not strictly speaking accurate, in two ways: first, because it is not strict enough, and second, because it is too strict. The real rule is that a class *with an explicit cctor* is guaranteed to have the cctor called *immediately* preceding the first access to a member, not sooner or later, and a class *without an explicit cctor* is guaranteed to be so initialized *at some time before the first field is accessed*.

Comment: @wardies: Sadly, the C# MSDN documentation contains a number of such errors. Sometimes the errors are simplifications for pedagogic reasons, sometimes features changed and the writers were never brought up to date, sometimes errors crept in and the changes were insufficiently vetted by experts. I tried to fix the docs where I could, but I had many pressing concerns.

Comment: @wardies: Now, even though the first heuristic is not, strictly speaking necessary, you can see why the jitter team would like to leave it in. Delaying the call to the cctor *as long as is allowed by the rules* is not a desirable situation if doing so produces a program that is confusing and weird. People have a reasonable expectation that their static fields will be initialized when a static method is running, even if the method doesn't touch it. The heuristic is cheap at runtime and makes good behaviour, so why not?

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks. I deleted my original comment because I realised that this class was not defined as `static class` so I thought I was being stupid. (For the record, I was referencing this para): _"The jitter is also within its rights to use a heuristic to decide whether or not a call to a static method that touches no field triggers the cctor; in this case apparently it does so, unnecessarily."_

Comment: @wardies: A static class is just a fiction of the C# language; there's no such thing from the CLR's perspective. From the CLR perspective a static class is merely a perfectly normal *abstract final class* that contains only static members. Abstract keeps it from being instantiated, final keeps it from being extended.  There are no special rules for cctors in a static class compared to any other normal class.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. Appreciate it.